# iOS Image View does not render image until touched

Tags: uitableview, uiview, uiimage

I have a table. Each cell of this table is an another table transformed at -90 degree angle. Each cell of this transformed table has an image. These images are coming from server over GCD thread and when image is available, I cal table relaodData but for some reason, the image is not shown/rendered until I touch and try to scroll that table cells. So seems like setNeedsDisplay API is not kind of doing its job at right time. I understand it does call this method at the end of run-loop but if it means my runloop os busy doing something else then how do I find out what else does it doing and hence not finding the time to render? OR is it something else?

Comment: (+1 to Dade's comment; you need to accept and/or upvote answers on your 9 previous questions!) -- also, how are you calling `setNeedsDisplay`?  from the GCD thread or in the main thread or?  Maybe show a bit of code to go with this.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I voted and accepted my previous questions, I didnt know about it.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tryed using UIScrollView instead of UITableView for horiyontal scrolling?
You can easily define how many pages/images you want to display, use the paging functionality to scroll between them.